# How to write a merge query for an array of struct in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table with following columns:-

```sql
super_user TRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>,
admin ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>>,
user ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>>,
```

I am trying to write a merge query that will check for any changes in any field of any record of these columns. Notice that admin and user columns are of type array.How can I write a merge statement for these columns ?

Comment: Could you provide the sample data and expected output?